# Magento2 Product detail page add checkbox before add to cart button

Tags: magento2.1.5

In a Product Detail Page after Quantity add checkbox when checkbox button is checked than "add to cart" button stay active if not click on checkbox than disable button.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried anything from your side?

Comment: yes i have done it.. look @ Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have override the in custom theme file addtocart.phtml file after qty box i have added a checkbox. like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="add_to_cart" id="add_to_cart">
```

after that at the end of the page  i have add custom jquery for check box is checked or not..!  like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    jQuery(".tocart").click(function(){
        if (jQuery('.control #add_to_cart').is(':checked') === false) {
                    alert("Please check at least one item");
                    return false;
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

and it's work..! try it.